# Getting page number of pdf file Titanium Studio iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf, webview, scroll, titanium-mobile

I am creating an app to read PDF file. I'm using WebView to load the PDF file. Below is the code:

```
var wv = Ti.UI.createWebView({
           backgroundColor:"gray", 
           border:1,
           height:410,
           url : "file.pdf"
         });

win.add(wv);
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to get the page number of the PDF and to navigate page by page. I did not find any way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible with Titanium WebView component as it is. There are several [PDF Reader plugins](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/listing?1080954371&q=pdf) available for Titanium which you could use.

You can also try to use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and include it in WebView and try to manage the things you want. But i never tried to use pdf.js before i in Titanium or mobile environments at all.